# Laravel 4.1 merge query result objects in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, merge

i have the following code:

```
    foreach($followlist as $followed)
{
    echo $followed;
    $query = Product::where('prod_user_id','=', $followed)->get();
}
```

i want to save the resultant queries into the $query variable but it only saves the last query in it.
I need to use the resultant query in another loop which extracts data from it as such:

```
    foreach ($query as $pro){
$vidpic = $pro->prod_pic_id;
$vpic = Media::find($vidpic)->path;
...blabla
}
```

i tried using $query[] to save it all but it cant be used in the second loop.
how may I achieve that? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write multiple where using following pattern

```
  $query = new Product;
    foreach($followlist as $followed)
    {
        echo $followed;
        $query->where('prod_user_id','=', $followed);
    }
    // retrieve all products using `get()`
    $products = $query->get();



   foreach ($products as $pro)
   {
          $vidpic = $pro->prod_pic_id;
          $vpic = Media::find($vidpic)->path;
           ...blabla
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly!